# Vue transition group use enter/leave instead of move

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-transitions

Using [vue transition-groups](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions), is there a way to trigger the leave + enter transitions instead of the move transitions for moving elements?

It should leave, and enter at the new position instead. The move transition only seems to work with transformations.

Playground: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqJEmV

HTML:

```
<div id="flip-list-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#flip-list-demo',
  data: {
    items: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function () {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    }
  }
})
```

CSS:

```
/** Should NOT use this: **/
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

/** Should use this instead: **/
.flip-list-enter-active, .flip-list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.flip-list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.flip-list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with `.flip-list-move` is there any reason why you don't want to use it

Comment: @SirDad The move only seems to work with transforms, I need a different animation

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue so I thought I'd post here for anyone else who finds this later:

The solution that worked for me is to utilize the `key` attribute to force vue to treat the item that moved as a "new" item. That way the [enter/leave](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions) animations get fired instead of the [move](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions).

I forked your pen to show how it can work:  https://codepen.io/josh7weaver/pen/eYOXxed?editors=1010

As you can see, one downside to this approach is that you have to increase the complexity of your data model for it to work. i.e. before you had a simple array, after we have an array of objects since each object needs to be responsible for its own key.

There are many different ways you could generate a unique ID for the item you want to trick vue into thinking is "new," but the method I used I just copied and pasted from a public gist.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @julius - if this worked for you could you mark it as the solution so its a bit clearer for others? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware:

- Enter is triggered when a new item is added
- Leave is triggered when an item is removed
- Move is triggered when the order changes

If you want to only trigger an enter to leave transition you would have to add/remove an item from the array instead of shuffle.

Here is an example:

```
shuffle: function () {
    this.items = [1,3,5,7,9];
}
```